# Haskell : Two different functions using the same where clauses

Tags: performance, function, haskell

Is there a way I can make a structure for 2 different functions using the same where clauses?

My code:

```
bonusColBullet :: Bonus -> Bullet -> World -> World
bonusColBullet bn@(Bonus{bnpos=pos}) b w@(World{bullets=bs, bonuses=bns, score=s})
    | doBoxesCollide bnlp bnrp blp brp = w{bullets=delete b bs, bonuses=delete bn bns, score=incVal s}
    | otherwise = w
    where
        blp = bpos' - bSizeH --bullet corners
        brp = bpos' + bSizeH
        bnlp = pos - bnSizeH --bonus obj corners
        bnrp = pos + bnSizeH
        bpos' = bpos b
        incVal s@(Score{sval=sv, multiplier}) = s{sval=sv+multiplier}

enemyColBullet :: Enemy -> Bullet -> World -> World
enemyColBullet e@(Enemy{epos=pos}) b w@(World{bullets=bs, enemies=es, score=s})
    | doBoxesCollide elp erp blp brp = w{bullets=delete b bs, enemies=delete e es, score=incVal s}
    | otherwise = w
    where
        blp = bpos' - bSizeH -- bullet corners
        brp = bpos' + bSizeH
        elp = pos - eSizeH -- enemy corners
        erp = pos + eSizeH
        bpos' = bpos b
        incVal s@(Score{sval=sv, multiplier}) = s{sval=sv+multiplier}
```

Because like this it looks very inefficient to me, so I figured there should be a way to only have to write the where clause ones and to somehow make it includeable for both functions?

If anyone could help me out on this it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: Please show us your actual code so that we may help you.

Comment: @AaditMShah I've edited my question with the actual code, hope this helps.

Comment: It looks very much like you could factor out the code that calculates collisions, since that's what is common between them.  Try to break these large functions into smaller ones.  When you have more than 3 expressions in a where clause, it might be a good idea to start thinking about refactoring things.

Comment: Where are `bpos'`, `bSizeH`, and the rest coming from?  Are these constants?  If so, then make a function that is `bulletCollides` that takes a position and returns a `Bool`.

Comment: @bheklilr That's what I thought too but I don't know how I can do this since both functions calculate the same values using the positions of 2 objects, but use different objects for this that require a different function to get their positions from.

Comment: @bheklilr bSizeH indeed is a constant. bpos' however is not: it get the 'bpos' value from the object b (the Bullet that is checked for collision against). In otherwords: the position of the regarding bullet.

Comment: It would really help if we knew all of your types.  What are the types of `blp`, `brp`, `elp`, `erp`?  Is position just some instance of `Num`?  If so, why not `positionsCollide :: Position -> Position -> Bool` and then `positionsCollide (bulletPosition bullet) (enemyPosition enemy)`, it doesn't need to know about what kinds of objects are colliding, just about their positions.

Comment: @bheklilr Well the problem is it needs to know the objects colliding to be able to know their sizes (bSizeH for example: half the size of a bullet, or eSizeH: half the size of an enemy) and to be able to update the World State accordingly to the object hit (e.g. to remove a bullet and enemy or a bullet and bonus object).

Comment: As for Position: it is simply defined as (Float, Float) within the Gloss library that I'm using here. So blp, brp, elp, erp also are of the type (Float, Float).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! You're right that this can be factored out. One cool feature in Haskell which may help you is *ambiguity*. Haskell has two sorts of ambiguity, and you can use either one in this case. The first sort of ambiguity is called *parametric types*, for example the list type `[x]` exists for all `x` no matter what `x` is, so there are actually a lot of different functions `reverse :: [x] -> [x]`, one for every type which you can put inside those lists. The only problem is that sometimes you want a *constraint* on these parameters, so that you can *do* stuff with them (`reverse` is constrained by the total ambiguity; it can't do anything to the elements but can only reorder them and possibly drop or repeat them). The *constrained ambiguity* is a feature called **type classes**. Here's how I'd use them to fit your case:

```
type Size = ____ -- fill this in with whatever that type actually is.

class Sprite s where
    kill :: s -> World -> World
    position :: s -> Size
    size :: s -> Size

instance Sprite Bullet where
    kill b w = w{bullets = delete b (bullets w)}
    position = bpos
    size = const bSizeH -- constant for all bullets, right?

instance Sprite Bonus where
    kill bn w = w{bonuses = delete bn (bonuses w)}
    position = bnpos
    size = const bnSizeH

instance Sprite Enemy where
    kill e w = w{enemies = delete e (enemies w)}
    position = epos
    size = const eSizeH
```

Now you can write something more generic:

```
 collides :: (Sprite x, Sprite y) => x -> y -> Bool
 collides x y = doBoxesCollide (px - sx) (px + sx) (py - sy) (py + sy)
     where px = position x
           py = position y
           sx = size x
           sy = size y

addScore :: World -> World
addScore w = w{score = s{sval = sval s + multiplier s}} where s = score w

killCollision :: (Sprite x, Sprite y) => x -> y -> World -> World
killCollision x y = if collides x y then addScore . kill x . kill y else id
```

We've gone up from your 22 lines up to 27 lines, but we now have a lot of smaller parts interacting in clearer ways, and no repeating ourselves. It's an artistic choice whether this is worth it or not -- it often helps longer-term maintenance of a program, but if you're just trying to get a program out there often copy-paste is faster.

So now where you would have written `bonusColBullet bn b w` you can just write `killCollision bn b w` and it does the same thing, and so does `killCollision e b w` for enemies `e`. But you've got a little more power. Suppose you want to have enemies eat bonuses that they collide with: but you do not get a score for that. Then that would be `if collides e bn then kill bn else id`. Or you might decide that different sprites have different `points` which they are worth; then you add to the `Sprite` class `points :: x -> Points` (where Points is whatever Num type your points are -- presumably `Integer` but I didn't want to assume). You modify `addScore` to become:

```
addScore :: (Sprite x, Sprite y) => x -> y -> World -> World
addScore x y w = w{score = s{sval = newscore}
    where s = score w
          newscore = sval s + multiplier s * (points x + points y)
```

and you modify `killCollision` by replacing `addScore` with `addScore x y`. That's it. Now different enemies or bonuses can be worth different amounts. With a little more work, you can have an enemy who eats a bonus get the points from that bonus (so that if you kill them you still get the bonus points). Stuff like that.

Comment: Great solution and very well described, thank you very much! I had thought about using types/classes for it before but I hadn't got a clue how to apply it in this case, thank you for your time to write such detailled explanation and code on how to use it, I'm sure this will help me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can make a structure for 2 different functions using the same where clauses

`where` gives you a binding with local scope. So to share that between two functions, they have to be "inside" the `where` scope.

Easier is to float the where clause out. E.g. calculate it once and pass `x` and `y` to your functions.

```
main = do
   let x = func a - c
       y = func' b - c

   someFunc x y
   someOtherFunc x y
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this is not an option for my case. I realized an example code isn't close enough to my actual code so I updated my question with the actual code.